# Is there an equivalent of torch.distributions.Normal in LibTorch, the C++ API for PyTorch?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am implementing a policy gradient algorithm with stochastic policies and since "ancillary" non-PyTorch operations are slow in Python, I want to implement the algorithm in C++. Is there a way to implement a normal distribution in the PyTorch C++ API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributions/normal.py) actually calls the C++ back-end in the `at::` namespace ([CPU](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5ab36ec98ba28b61ac3be57427d67ad8e1f0bab4/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/DistributionTemplates.h#L173), [CUDA](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/34523b70c1369024f805a0480bc39a5f21e64a03/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/DistributionTemplates.h#L407), [where I found this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-distributions-categorical/45747)). Until the PyTorch team and/or contributors implement a front-end in LibTorch, you can work around it with something like this (I only implemented `rsample()` and `log_prob()` because it's what I need for this use case):

```cpp
constexpr double lz = log(sqrt(2 * M_PI));
class Normal {
    torch::Tensor mean, stddev, var, log_std;
public:
    Normal(const torch::Tensor &mean, const torch::Tensor &std) : mean(mean), stddev(std), var(std * std), log_std(std.log()) {}


    torch::Tensor rsample() {
        auto device = torch::cuda::is_available() ? torch::kCUDA : torch::kCPU;
        auto eps = torch::randn(1).to(device);
        return this->mean + eps * this->stddev;
    }

    torch::Tensor log_prob(const torch::Tensor &value) {
        // log [exp(-(x-mu)^2/(2 sigma^2)) / (sqrt(2 pi) * sigma)] = 
        // = log [exp(-(x-mu)^2/(2 sigma^2))] - log [sqrt(2 pi) * sigma] = 
        // = -(x - mu)^2 / (2 sigma^2) - log(sigma) - log(sqrt(2 pi))
        return -(value - this->mean)*(value - this->mean) / (2 * this->var) - this->log_std - lz;
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice. Hey, what is the `this->`? What are they and where are they from exactly?

Comment: It allows for accessing the attributes defined on line 3 (mean, stddev etc)

Comment: Thank. I have a stupid question you might care to answer. I've been trying to figure it out all day.. Question: If I use tensors here for the mean and std is that considered a 'multivariate distribution'? I'm pretty sure it is. 
Also, not so stupid question, do you know how I might get a diagonal multivariate distribution with this?
Tensorflow has a `MultivariateNormalDiag` distrubution I'm trying to write in C++ but I'm not sure what it is exactly, even though I've looked at the [source code](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MultivariateNormalDiag).

Comment: From what I understood from the documentation page, it is simply a multivariate normal distribution, and yes, in principle if you use tensors for the mean and std you get a multivariate normal distribution, but I have not tested this use case.